# Usage of conversion bitween the type with bitwise and non-bitwise

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, attributes

Recently, I start to take a look at `dm-cache` which is a one of the kernel module.
It has some tricky source code which converts between bitwise type and non-bitwise type.
Here is the definition of variable type.

```
typedef uint64_t dm_block_t;
typedef dm_block_t __bitwise__ dm_oblock_t;
```

And Here is some inline source code which converts between them.

```
static inline dm_oblock_t to_oblock(dm_block_t b)
{
        return (__force dm_oblock_t) b;
}

static inline dm_block_t from_oblock(dm_oblock_t b)
{
        return (__force dm_block_t) b;
}
```

Why did they code like that?
Can't we just use `uint64_t` or at least `dm_block_t`? I'm very confused since in the module there are many type conversion between bitwise and non-bitwise type variable.

According to google, they said usage of `__bitwise__` prevents long type casting

Then why not just use bitwise variable always? Thank you for your helps.

Comment: There is even a [comment in the header file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.6/source/drivers/md/dm-cache-block-types.h#L14) about these types: "It's helpful to get sparse to differentiate between indexes into the origin device, indexes into the cache device, and indexes into the discard bitset."

Comment: Actually, I see the comments "It's helpful to get sparse to differentiate between indexes into the origin device, indexes into the cache device, and indexes into the discard bitset." But I don't know what it means. Can make it more clear?

Comment: I think it's just to add strong typing for the "sparse" semantic checker, so the checker would complain if you assigned a `dm_block_t` value to a `dm_oblock_t` variable, for example. Such an assignment is perfectly legal in C, but the semantic checker is checking for potential programming errors that are legal C.

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree with your opinion.